# How to filter get request by name and enums, when object is inside a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have an API that stores cards into a HashMap<Integer, Card>, I can send a GET to this API in two ways:

http://localhost:8080/app/cards - Will list me all cards (JSON) like:

```
[
{
    "atk": 5,
    "class": "QUALQUER",
    "def": 2,
    "desc": "UM TESTE REX CARD PRE-ALPHA EDITION",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "T-REX",
    "type": "CRIATURA"
},
{
    "atk": 5,
    "class": "QUALQUER",
    "def": 2,
    "desc": "UM TESTE REX CARD PRE-ALPHA EDITION",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "T-REX",
    "type": "CRIATURA"
}]
```

I can also get by ID with http://localhost:8080/app/cards/1 (1 is the ID)

My get by ID

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Carta getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return repositorio.getID(id);
}
```

However, I still need to create a GET by name, by type and by class. the name will retrieve only one result, but class and type are enums and I don't know how to filter each Card object inside the HashMap, since its a HashMap<Integer, Card>, the get by ID was easy. There is no need to create a database as this is an exercise, but everything I try fails, including creating the GET request, i'm starting by copying the above method and changing @Path to "name", but it gives me errors too.

Card class:

```
public class Card {

private int id;

private String name;
private String desc;
private int atk;
private int def;
private CardType type; //enum
private CardClass class;  //enum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the `HashMap` using Java 8 streams:

```
List<Card> cards = cardsHashMap.entrySet().stream()
        //filter cards by type
        .filter(e -> Card.CRIATURA.equals(e.getValue().getType())) 
        //map to the corresponding Card object 
        .map(Entry::getValue) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `.map(Entry::getValie)` would be better: it would return the map object instead of creating a new one (that could be costly). And with enums it's safer to use `==` instead of `.equals()` as they are unique instances.

Answer (score 1):

`Map` has method `values()` which returns a `Collection` of all the values (cards) inside this map, and this collection may be filtered using Stream API.

The search methods should be implemented inside repository class.

```java
// repository class
public List<Card> getByCardType(CardType type) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(type);
    return cardsMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(card -> type == card.getType())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public List<Card> getByCardClass(CardClass cardClass) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(cardClass);
    return cardsMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(card -> cardClass == card.getCardClass())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

However, if cardType/cardClass are immutable per card instance, it could be convenient to use a couple of other maps like `Map<CardType, List<Cards>> cardsByType`, `Map<CardClass, List<Cards>> cardsByClass` in the repository class.

Also, the methods of populating/saving and deleting/removing the entries in the repository should be created/modified using `Map::computeIfAbsent` and `Map::computeIfPresent` respectively:

```java
// caching repository
public List<Card> getByCardType(CardType type) {
    return cardsByType.get(type);
}

public List<Card> getByCardClass(CardClass cardClass) {
    return cardsByClass.get(cardClass);
}

public boolean addCard(Card card) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(card);
    if (cardsMap.containsKey(card.getId())) {
        return false; // the card already exists in the repo, nothing to add
    }

    cardsMap.put(card.getId(), card);
    cardsByType.computeIfAbsent(card.getType(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(card);
    cardsByClass.computeIfAbsent(card.getCardClass(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(card);

    return true; // card added successfully
}

public boolean removeCard(Card card) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(card);
    if (!cardsMap.containsKey(card.getId())) {
        return false; // the card does not exist in the repo, nothing to remove
    }

    cardsMap.remove(card.getId());
    cardsByType.computeIfPresent(card.getType(), (k, v) -> {
        v.remove(card); 
        return v;
    });
    cardsByClass.computeIfPresent(card.getCardClass(), (k, v) -> {
        v.remove(card); 
        return v;
    });

    return true; // card removed successfully
}
```